# csh: redirecting output from foreach

Tags: pipe, csh, for

In csh: How do I redirect the output from a `foreach`-loop to a pipe?

This works but uses a temp file:

```
set tmpfile=/tmp/file                                                                                                         
true > $tmpfile                                                                                                               
foreach v (`set | awk -e '{print $1}' |grep -v prompt2`);                                                                     
eval if'($?'$v' && ${#'$v'} <= 1) echo scalar'$v'="$'$v'"' >> $tmpfile                                                        
eval if'($?'$v' && ${#'$v'} > 1) echo array'$v'="$'$v'"' >> $tmpfile                                                          
end                                                                                                                           
cat $tmpfile | parallel --shellquote | perl -pe 's/^scalar(\S+).=/set $1=/ or s/^array(\S+).=(.*)/set $1=($2)/;'
```

I would like to get rid of the temp file and use a pipe instead. So something like this (does not work):

```
( foreach v (`set | awk -e '{print $1}' |grep -v prompt2`);                                                                   
eval if'($?'$v' && ${#'$v'} <= 1) echo scalar'$v'="$'$v'"'                                                                    
eval if'($?'$v' && ${#'$v'} > 1) echo array'$v'="$'$v'"'                                                                      
end ) | parallel --shellquote | perl -pe 's/^scalar(\S+).=/set $1=/ or s/^array(\S+).=(.*)/set $1=($2)/;'
```

Comment: Unless things changed in csh, `if` is not implemented as a syntactical element but rather as a builtin command. This would make it hard to redirect complex code. Is there any reason why you like to write script in csh syntax at all?

Comment: Yes: I would like to access all variables set (not just setenvs) and output a program that sets these to the current values.

Comment: So you are using csh as interactive shell and like to run a sourced script in this interactive shell?

Answer (score 0):

Piping to/from control structures is an error in C Shell. The workaround to pipe to/from control structures is to create a script or FIFO file. Here's an example as file.

```
echo '\
# Functions\
alias function '\''( set argv = ( \\\!* ) ; source ~/.cshfuncs )'\' >> ~/.cshrc
echo 'switch ("$1")\
  case 'myfunc':\
    shift\
    foreach v (`set | awk -e '\''{print $1}'\'' |grep -v prompt2`)\
      eval if'\''($?'\''$v'\'' && ${#'\''$v'\''} <= 1) echo scalar'\''$v'\''="$'\''$v'\''"'\''\
      eval if'\''($?'\''$v'\'' && ${#'\''$v'\''} > 1) echo array'\''$v'\''="$'\''$v'\''"'\''\
    end\
    exit\
  default:\
    echo "Function $1 not set."\
    exit\
endsw' > ~/.cshfuncs
```

And here's an example as FIFO.

```
mkfifo ~/fifo
echo 'foreach v (`set | awk -e '\''{print $1}'\'' |grep -v prompt2`)\
eval if'\''($?'\''$v'\'' && ${#'\''$v'\''} <= 1) echo scalar'\''$v'\''="$'\''$v'\''"'\''\
eval if'\''($?'\''$v'\'' && ${#'\''$v'\''} > 1) echo array'\''$v'\''="$'\''$v'\''"'\''\
end' > ~/fifo & ( source ~/fifo ) | parallel --shellquote | perl -pe 's/^scalar(\S+).=/set $1=/ or s/^array(\S+).=(.*)/set $1=($2)/;'
```